# Linux, C: how can I get return value from thread which greate than 4G in a 32bits OS?

Tags: c, linux, 32-bit

I am running `32 bits` of OS.
Now the thread I created will return a int value which it could be larger than `4G`.
How can I receive this value from my `main()` function by `pthread_join()`?
Looks like in `32 bits` system, `(void *)` is 4 bytes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void* thread_function(void)
{
    uint64_t nbytes  = 0;
    //assign values to nbytes, it could be larger than 4G.
    return (void *)nbytes;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    uint64_t nbytes;

    pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, &thread_function, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id,(void**)&nbytes); 
}
```

Comment: Why not send `&nbytes` as your currently-NULL arg to `pthread_create` and simply cast-and-set the value via address in your function ?

Comment: First of all your `thread_function` is of a wrong type. It should take arguments. Now guess what? You can use these arguments to pass values back and forth. And the `void*` return type is really not intended to be casted to a non-pointer types.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
void* thread_function(void *)
{
    uint64_t nbytes  = 0;
    //assign values to nbytes, it could be larger than 4G.

    void *retval = malloc (sizeof (nbytes));
    memcpy (retval, &nbytes, sizeof (nbytes));
    return retval;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    uint64_t nbytes;

    pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, &thread_function, NULL);

    void *ret;
    pthread_join(thread_id, &ret); 
    memcpy (nbytes, ret, sizeof (nbytes));
    free (ret);
}
```

This is a common pattern for transferring a value from one thread to another. The sending thread allocates memory, copies in the value, and passes a pointer. The receiving thread gets the pointer, copies out the value and frees the pointer.

Comment: The `thread_function` signature is invalid. As an alternative (and, I would say a safer) approach it can take a pointer to a pre-allocated buffer from the receiving thread and just fill it. It's a much better practice to have the allocating and the freeing code on the same level.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, fixed. This is a very standard pattern because it works even when the receiving thread has no idea how big the object is and even when the creation and joining of the thread are in very different places. I think in this case, it's worse to tie the allocation to the creation of the thread because it's not logically related to where the result is created or consumed.

Comment: Well, yeah. The use case of the unknown object size makes a perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

David Schwartz's solution is well known but a bit too much to pass a simple integer; `malloc()` is expensive and not necessarily thread safe(highly unlikely but with all of the embeded stuff today…).

Picking up the idea of the first two commenters to the OP (WhozCraig and Eugene Sh.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thread_function(void *arg)
{
  /*
     No direct dereferencing
        *arg = 0xdeadbeefcafe;
     would give a compile error. With GCC it would be

     threadargs.c:8:5: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]

  */
  uint64_t *nbytes = arg;
  *nbytes = 0xdeadbeefcafe;
  // you can return a simple status here, for example an error
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread_id;
  uint64_t nbytes;

  pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thread_function, &nbytes);
  pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>  
  printf("nbytes =  %" PRIx64 "\n", nbytes);

  return 0;
}
```

Should do the job in another way, maybe a better one for this type of usage.

Disadvantage: every thread wants its own variable to fill, so it is a better fit for a fixed, small amount of threads, otherwise you are allocating from the heap and have won nothing, just the opposite: it would be more complicated to keep hold off all the `malloc()/free()`. David Schwartz's method would be much more apt in that case.

Comment: If you're using POSIX threads then `malloc()` will be thread safe.

Comment: Also GlibC >= 2.2 (at least, I think even earlier) but I have been burned too often to not give a hint to "better check first no matter how sure you are".